# PHP: selected not being written out to HTML

Tags: php, html, select

I have the following

```
<?php echo $d[17];?>
<select class="form-control" name="text_06" id="text_06_<?=$this->instanceID?>" class="form-control">
    <option value="--" <?php echo ($d[17]=='--' ? 'selected':'');?>>-</option>
    <option value="Full" <?php echo ($d[17] == 'Full' ? 'selected':'');?>>The full review period</option>
    <option value="Half" <?php echo ($d[17] == 'Half' ? 'selected':'');?>>50% of the review period</option>
    <option value="None" <?php echo ($d[17] == 'None' ? 'selected':'');?>>None of the above</option>
</select>
```

It outputs "Full" as expected but the option is not being selected i.e. the `selected` text is not being written. If I move the ternary operator to anywhere outside the select menu, even to the text of that option, it displays "selected"

I have also tried using `selected="selected"` to no avail

Any idea? Chrome v70 being used. `var_dump($d[17])` of the variable gives:

```
string(4) "Full"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189629/discussion-on-question-by-pee2pee-php-selected-not-being-written-out-to-html).